# Can not delete action in Good Morning Routine

Tags: actions-on-google

I am the owner of google action addon called ["Israel News"](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000d51b1cd748?hl=en) and one of the intent can be add to routine from the link of this addon, but when adding to the Good Morning routine there is no option to remove it,
I tried everything :

- pressing the line of the "Gallay News" nothing happened
- pressing the 2 line in the side doesn't give me option to delete
- delete cache of Home app
- it is not only me with this problem

picture attached with 2 actions that can be delete
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj2g0.jpg)

Please help me to solve it, can it be something in me google action code?

Answer (score 0):

When you see your list of actions in a routine, you need to click on the one you want to remove. Then you are led to another page where you can **"Remove Action"**.

Make sure you press the **"Save"** button at the bottom of the page to confirm the change.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Nick , but the action doesn't open any new page like the other actions in the routine, it look like this action isn't clickable